# Color on Only Alpha Channel in GIMP

Tags: color, gimp

I am trying to create a map of a building in GIMP . The building is color coded by section with 30% opacity, and the space between the colors is currently white because that is the color of the base image that everything is being built onto.

The layer that is to have the walkway colors was put next to last in the order. It is just a transparent layer. I put it near the bottom of the layer order in effort to use a paint tool to color over the other layers and only paint the Alpha channels without painting any of the department colors. I remember being able to lock upper layers to do this. Every time I've tried, I have locked the pixels, position, and alpha in different combinations. Whenever I've started to paint over the white it paints everywhere. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Alpha channels and layers are not the same thing. Can you please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/163483/edit) to clarify which on you mean? Maybe uploading a few screencaps to http://imgur.com and linking to them will help clarify the problem.

Comment: Hi. Could you show us a screeen shot of your image and layers, and show what you are trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/B7mjgBB This is the link to an image that I hope explains things

Answer (score 1):

If you wan to paint the transparent pixels and only them, set the paint tool to "Behind" mode. If you want to only paint on the opaque pixels, set the alpha-lock on the layer.

[image]

Comment: This sort of worked. When I painted, it colored the white, but I was also able to see it behind the semi-transparent layers on top. https://imgur.com/a/B7mjgBB This is an explanation of my project

Comment: As I understand it you expect Gimp to guess where the path ways are. I see two ways, to a cumulative alpha-to-selection on the colored areas (could be simpler if they are all in a group) and invert the selection before painting, or use the bucket-fill with "Line-art detection" and specify the other layers for the line art.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted because it was said to be unreadable. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX. Now it also is.

Comment: Can you please edit the first paragraph of your text. The grammar is appalling.  I would edit it for you, but I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to say. Sorry.

Comment: You didn't have to delete it!!  Just fix it. The issues are "well paint",  "no matter it covers", "new paintind", "prevent ... to hide", and "below as well afterwards a before". I understand you are talking about using layers, which is a valid answer to the question.

Comment: I can take a stab at it, but I'm kind of guessing.  Try this perhaps "You can easily paint what you want on a new layer. It doesn't matter if it covers the colored areas of the underlying layers. ,You can prevent the new painted layer from hiding what's below, either before or after painting it".